# What steps are needed to document `package main` in Godoc?

Tags: go, documentation, godoc

Godoc is a great tool for documenting packages, however it seems to be less useful when it's used against `package main`. I'll see an output that only displays the notes I've written to myself using `//BUG` and subdirectories.

Godoc only displays exported functions and seems to have no way to display unexported / functions from main. I would find it useful to see a list of functions in main. Since this isn't supported, I tend to shove a list of functions at the top of the package description but this feels like a workaround.

Since I have to manually update the list of functions, I often put as much code in packages as I can so it's exported and thus documented. Is this a good idea? What should I do about the list of functions in main?

Example:

```
COMMAND DOCUMENTATION

Package main implements a web server, template renderer and DAL for MySQL.

<filename.go>

    <function>(<signature>)

main.go

    main()
    bootstrap() error
    <more functions here>


BUGS

    [filename.go] <whatever...>


SUBDIRECTORIES

    auth
    common
    debug
    storage
    <more packages here>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to build a slightly modified version of `godoc` to document main packages.

Please see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5727.

tl;dr:

1. Modify the following line in `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/godoc/server.go`

   ```
   - info.IsMain = pkgname == "main"
   + info.IsMain = false && pkgname == "main"
   ```
2. Build and install with `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`.

`$GOPATH/bin/godoc` should now behave as you wish.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, you already have the answer to your question. I can think of two alternative solutions:

1. Maintain a fork of godoc that shows functions for `main` packages. (And you'd then have to run an instance of it yourself on a web server. The downside is that people going straight to godoc.org for your package documentation will miss out.)
2. Separate your `main` packages into sub-packages such that the `main` package is small or minimal. Documentation could then be read in those sub-packages. But as far as I know, this is not in widespread practice.

I think in general, godoc is for *package* documentation. Documentation for `main` packages is really only useful to people editing the source code of that package---so the documentation conceivably doesn't need to be publicized. On the other hand, this lacks the nice presentation/organization of godoc.

As a compromise, if you really want to publicize the documentation, I'd recommend an overview of the architecture of your program rather than a play-by-play of each function.