# How to create document with godoc?

Tags: go, godoc

I create simple go with comment in the application to the function and the package
I tried godoc -html and my application and the result

```
<!--
    Copyright 2009 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
    license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
-->

<!--
        Note: Static (i.e., not template-generated) href and id
        attributes start with "pkg-" to make it impossible for
        them to conflict with generated attributes (some of which
        correspond to Go identifiers).
-->

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.ANALYSIS_DATA = ;
        document.CALLGRAPH = ;
        </script>



                <p>
Package main provides logic ...
</p>
```

why I didn't see my other document ? and why the `<p>` for the package has spaces

```
// Package main provides logic.
package main
import (

}

some types.....

func main() {
}

// doLogic .....
// .....
// ....
func (sm *myI) doLogic (s *myStruct) bool {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unexported identifiers are not documented by default. Set at least `?m=all` to see them:

> The presentation mode of web pages served by godoc can be controlled with the "m" URL parameter; it accepts a comma-separated list of flag names as value:
>
> ```
> all     show documentation for all declarations, not just the exported ones
> methods show all embedded methods, not just those of unexported anonymous fields
> src     show the original source code rather then the extracted documentation
> ```
>
> For instance, https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/?m=all shows the documentation for all (not just the exported) declarations of package big.
>   https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc

Comment: what should I need to add to the command  godoc -html -src c:/Users/go/src/myProject ?

Comment: can I run it with godoc -http=:6060 ? P.S how I can export method ?

Comment: i run this command godoc -http=:6060 -goroot=$GOHOME
 and then i run http://localhost:6060?m=all then I succeed to get the struct but not the function

Comment: The main package can't be documented by the default godoc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778556/what-steps-are-needed-to-document-package-main-in-godoc